# orientdb with image, graph, sql and ORecordBytes

Tags: sql, image, graph, binary-data, orientdb

I have been looking on how to save image in orientdb(as graph database), and found this:

http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Binary-Data.html

Note, I am only discussing the technique involving ORecordBytes

However, few questions:

(1) It seems the sql command 'CREATE CLUSTER' is missing many of the parameters one can provide through the java api. What are the defaults? is it even possible?

http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/SQL-Create-Cluster.html

(2) Until now, I have been using SQL (script) to create my entities.
In order to work together with ORecordBytes, I tried something like that:

```
ORecordBytes record = new ORecordBytes("Binary data".getBytes());
record.save();
String cmd = String.format(originalQuery, record.getIdentity().toString());
```

When printing the query, it looks fine (partial):
    CREATE VERTEX ... SET my_id=$some_id_new[0].value, name="Cool name", image=#3:-2

Ofcourse, the image property is the one who got the rid.
However, I don't think #3:-2 really exists.
I tried to query it, even though I have no type in there, but couldn't.
Also, when doing a query on the vertex using the console, there is no image property.

How can I do that it then?

p.s.
I am using an SQL script because I need an auto increment field which aren't supported natively. The script is updating a counter table, getting the new value, and creating the new vertex (including some edges). That seems to be easier.

## Edit (1)

(1) Lvca pointed out negative RIDs are temporary.
I am a bit confused why it would be temporary if I called save().
Otherwise, what does save() do?

I will however try to run commit after it.

(2) Not sure why the script is important, since it's obviously getting a wrong record id RID, but Lvca asked and I comply ^^

```
BEGIN\n\
LET user_id_new = UPDATE CCounter INCREMENT value = 1 RETURN BEFORE $current.value WHERE name='user'
LET cuser = CREATE VERTEX CUser SET user_id=$user_id_new[0].value,\
  name="%s", create_date=%s, rooms=(SELECT FROM CRooms WHERE room_id IN %s),\
  image=%s\n\
COMMIT\n\
RETURN $user_id_new[0].value\n
```

Notes:
* The line feed at the end is because orientdb sql script requires them after every line
* The extra backslash at each line is because I am using a properties file, which require that as part of a single variable (the first line is actually "my_query=\", but it's not part of the script though)
Note that when printing it, it looks good (no backslash at the end, and each line at it's own)
* Not the return value is simply a Long(id). Don't need more than that.

(3) I have to say I was hoping I could insert both the properties and the image of an entity in one transaction, I am starting to feel like it's not gonna happen. Is there no way to do it?

(4) Also, in the meanwhile I tried some other way, which doesn't work either. Feel free to comment on it too:

- First, I run the script above, with slight modifications:

  - Removed the 'image' field from the script
  - Returned the entire data rater than id (return $cuser)
- Second, I used the following (java) to create the initial entity (without image):

  OCommandRequest req = graph.command(new OCommandScript("sql", cmd));
  vertex = req.execute();
  graph.commit();
- Third, I created an ORecordBytes variable, and saved it (and commit).

  ORecordBytes imgRec = new ORecordBytes(graph.getRawGraph(), imgBytes);
  imgRec.save();
  graph.commit();
- Fourth, I put the image record into the 'image' property of the vertex obtained previously, and commit

  vertex.setProperty("image", imgRec);
  vertex.save();
  graph.commit();

This, doesn't work as well. It seems to set the "image" property to a string, for some reason. the query at console return somtehing like that (truncated by console):

```
#3:2[-119, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82, 0, 0, 0, -
```

When printing imgRec.toString(), the string is VERY LONG (console can't show it all). However, it seems to contain many values (many negatives as well, at least near the end). ANd it ends like that (no line feeds, not that I can see)

```
, 69, 78, 68, -82, 66, 96, -126] v1
```

Also, I tried to replace 'setProperty' with
    ODocument doc = vertex.getRecord();
    doc.field("image", imgRec);
    doc.save();

And I tried to replace OrientVertex with Vertex (Also changed the types, not shown before)
    Vertex vertex = null;
    ...
    vertex = req.execute();

And I tried setting the property to getIdentity instead of the record:
    vertex.setProperty("image", imgRec.getIdentity());

All had the same result, a string in the field "image", instead of a LINK.

In the meantime, I will try to go back to my first attempt, and use commit after creating the imgRec. I will edit again when done.
Either way, I see many ways to accomplish this, many ways which in my opinion should work, and suggests on issues. Correct me if i'm wrong, so i'll know to open an issue in orientdb github.

P.S.
* The problem with the field being string, is well.. it's embedding the content. But also, I tried to ignore it and query the data s ORecordBytes. Obviously, didn't work. (can't cast String to ORecordBytes)
* Cluster id 3 is 'default'' at least on my database.

P.S. 2
You never asked, but the I am currently using version v2.0-M2.

Sorry for the long post, and thanks!

## Edit (2): Solution(?)

So, it finally works!

As far as I can tell, the problems were:

(1) I tried to set the ORecordBytes variable to the field. Even though I saw some places online doing it, it doesn't seem to work. You need to insert the identity of it (getIdentity()). If it's through sql, you can use toString() on getIdentity(), but still.

(2) Although I prefer to create my properties ahead, I didn't know the type of it, so this time I didn't. As a result, when tried to insert ORecordBytes.toString(), the result was a weird string, and orientdb automatically assigned a string type too the field.
Any further attempts, which were good, simply followed the assigned data type.

Note that 'DELETE PROPERTY CUser.image' did not work. kept saying Property doesn't exists.
However, through console I typed 'info class CUser', and you could clearly see the 'image' property with String data type.
Currently, I just used a different field (not sure how to fix this).

If anyone is interested, I did find a way to predefined the data type, but it has it's drawbacks:

```
CREATE PROPERTY CUser.img LINK
```

Note I am not specifying the link data type (e.g. link to Room vertex).

Last question though:

I am still not sure how to do it in one commit. Currently, I am creating ORecordBytes, calling save() + commit(), and then running sql query with the new rid.
Is there anyway to do this in one commit?

Answer (score 0):

Negative RIDs mean RIDs are temporary, so a transaction is running. OrientDB takes care to update them once the transaction is committed. Can you post your SQL script?

Comment: Shouldn't save() suppose to save the changes, regardless of an open transaction? Otherwise, what does it do? Also, I tried using both types of databaes (Tx and NoTx), it seems to be a known issue and can't be done, not really sure why (no need transactions for getting some data in a single query). I will edit my message to answer your question though.